# How to set model attribute to value of other attribute when saving - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When a user is created, which includes a 'screen_name' attribute, I would like to set the value of a user attribute called: 'username' to the value of screen_name, but downcase, by default.

I'm using active record and rails, what would be the best solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a `before_create` filter in your `app/models/user.rb` file:

```
before_create :set_username

def set_username
  self.username = screen_name.downcase
end
```

Comment: But if its before create would the screen_name exist yet?

Comment: Assuming you have something like `@user = User.new(params[:user])`, then `before_create` will have access to the screen_name attribute. `before_create` filters run after you've assigned stuff to your attributes, but right before it's saved to the database.